# PICK_CONTACT in xiaomi phone id column not found

Tags: android

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException

Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=131073, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/root_files/storage/3B44-17E3/DCIM/Camera/FB_IMG_1553740630380.jpg flg=0x1 }} to activity 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist. Available columns: [_display_name, _size]

working in other devices

Answer (score 0):

Try                `startActivityForResult(newIntent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI), REQUEST_PICK_CONTACT);`

Comment: for all devices or for xiaomi phone only?

Comment: ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI   not able to get user's mobile number in nokia device. only get first name and last name